# Shell script to print the lines which contains a word added by the user

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a file named data.txt, which contains the following:

```
1440;150;1000000;pizza;hamburger
1000;180;56124;coke;sprite;water;juice
566;40;10000;cake;pizza;coke
```

I want to make a program which asks for an input from the user then prints out the lines which contains the given word.

For example:

If I enter coke, it should print out the second and third line. If I enter hambuger it should only print out the first line.

Here is the code that I tried but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me please?

```
echo "Enter a word"`
read word 

while read line; do
numbersinthefile=$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f4);
if [ $numbersinthefile -eq $num ]; then
echo $line;
fi
done
```

Earlier I forgot to mention that I want the program to allow multiple inputs from the user. Example:

If I type in "pizza sprite", it gives me the first and second line.

Comment: By seeing your profile got to know you never select an answer as correct one, so please give it sometime to your question and then select any of the answer as correct one out of all to complete the thread @Tyler Joe

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter word which you want to look for in Input_file:"
read value

awk -v val="$value" '$0 ~ val'  Input_file
```

After running above code following is how it will work.

```
./script.ksh
Please enter word which you want to look for in Input_file:
coke
1000;180;56124;coke;sprite;water;juice
566;40;10000;cake;pizza;coke
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case you want to pass multiple values to script then how about passing them as an arguments to program itself?

```
cat script.ksh
for var in "$@"
do
  awk -v val="$var" '$0 ~ val'  Input_file
done
```

Then run script in following fashion.

```
script.ksh test coke cake etc
```

Comment: This works fine. But i forgot to mention in my post that I want the program to allow multiple inputs from the user. I will re-edit my post.

Comment: @TylerJoe, please try my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: It is not working. Maybe I'm making a mistake.  Do i need to use your first code, or just the edited?

Comment: @TylerJoe, just insie EDIT section one. Also make sure you are runing script by passing arguments too.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work, with two ore more values. I am using this in a case statement, maybe that influences the program.

Comment: @TylerJoe, it is working fine for me see this `./script1211.ksh coke pizza
1000;180;56124;coke;sprite;water;juice
566;40;10000;cake;pizza;coke
1440;150;1000000;pizza;hamburger
566;40;10000;cake;pizza;coke` Make sure you are giving CORRECT file name in place of Input_file let me know then?

Comment: What does cat that script.ksh do? Is it necessary?  My code looks like this:
case $1 in
 echo "Enter the words"
     read type 
     for var in "$@"
     do
     awk -v val="$type" '$0 ~ val' proba
     done
   ;;

And with this when i read in 2 or more inputs, it only shows the inputs. Clearly I am ruining some part of the code.

Comment: @TylerJoe, `cat` command is to print the script on post. You should use any editor in your server to create this script with a name eg--> `name.ksh` and give it permission as `755` then run this(you need to copy it from here under line from cat script one till last line) then run it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a simple [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), isn't it?

```
read -p "Enter a word: " word
grep -F "$word" file
```

Add `-w` to match `coke` with `coke` only, and not with `co` or `ok`.

```
read -p "Enter a word: " word
grep -Fw "$word" file
```

Comment: +1 Variants might include: Add the `-w` flag to match only whole word. Use `grep ';'"$word"'$'` if only the last word should be matched.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelKirschner, I added `-w`. As he wrote, `coke` should find lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in awk that accepts partial matches:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=";"                    # file field sep
    printf "Feed me text: "   # text for prompt
    if((getline s < "-")<=0)  # read user input
        exit                  # exit if unsuccessful
}
{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)        # iterate fields from file records >= 4
        if($i~s) {            # if match (~ since there was a space in eof NR==3) 
            print
            next              # only output each matching record once
        }
}' file
```

Output

```
Feed me text: coke
1000;180;56124;coke;sprite;water;juice
566;40;10000;cake;pizza;coke
```